# Power of a bluetooth sensor via smartphone android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible obtain the power of a bluetooth sensor via smartphone android.
If I have 2 bluetooth sensor, is it possible to understand, with smartphone android, if I have near sensor A or Sensor B

Answer (score 1):

To some extent you can do this using RSSI (receive signal strength), which is optionally provided by some BT hardware.  You can get RSSI information during device discovery.  RSSI isn't perfect though.  First, the measurements tend to be pretty imprecise.  Second, it's a measure of receive strength, which won't translate to distance if your other remote devices are not transmitting at the same power levels.

Comment: Good answer, couldn't add anything to that.